# How to Access Model Dialog Box content developed in Bootstrap using Selenium Web Driver and Java

Tags: java, selenium, model

I am trying to access model dialogue box (developed in Bootstrap) using Selenium Web Driver in Java, I am unable to do so. Here i wan tot access Title, Content and Button.

One more point is here xPath is dynamic, every time xPath is generating differently. I know that can be solved by partially matching the xPath.

So help me to solve this problem. Here I am attaching image of my model box design.

[image]

Here is code snippet

[image]

Here is code

```
<div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <div class="bootstrap-dialog-header">
                <div class="bootstrap-dialog-close-button" style="display: none;">
                    <button class="close">
                    ×
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="bootstrap-dialog-title" id="5f663313-d82d-4ab8-9712-6665e80a3654_title">
                Member Registration
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <div class="bootstrap-dialog-body">
                <div class="bootstrap-dialog-message">
                    Sample Message Sample Message Sample Message Sample Message Sample Message Sample Message.
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <div class="bootstrap-dialog-footer">
                <div class="bootstrap-dialog-footer-buttons">
                    <button class="btn btn-primary" id="353ab962-44d3-497f-8318-6db703b460d8">
                        Ok
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What's the bootstrap version? What's the bootstrap component name? Provide application link or sample html codeand what have you tried so far?

Comment: Check Attached Screenshot for code @Madhan

Comment: @Nikunj If you really want a solution, you need to provide HTML coded instead of screenshot and selenium code which have you tried as well????

Comment: Check Added HTML Code. Selenium code is already added in Answer that works well but i am unable to access Message from dialogue box. @Saurabh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//div[@class="bootstrap-dialog-title"] for Title

//div[@class="bootstrap-dialog-message"] for message

//div[@class="bootstrap-dialog-footer-buttons"]/button for buttton
```

Comment: Thanks this solution works for me to access all 3 elements of model.

Here Is code that works for me :

driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='bootstrap-dialog-title']")).getText();
 
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='bootstrap-dialog-message']")).getText();
 
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='bootstrap-dialog-footer-buttons']/button")).click();

Comment: @Nikunj avoid using `xPath` if you could get simply using `By.className`...it will faster than using `xPath`...

Answer (score 0):

```
driver.switchTo().activeElement();
Thread.sleep(5000);
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[contains(text(),'"+data+"')]")).click();
```

This Solve My Problem , 
I also wants to access Message but i am unable to access

Comment: I'm suggesting you for best practice you should implement `WebDriverWait` instead of `Thread.sleep`...